# Why did you stop using JSF?

Tags: java, jsf

This question goes out to those who have used JSF 1.1 through 2 as a web framework and then either gave it up or switched to something else, or even ported their application from JSF to something else.

The question is why? What led you to make this change? What framework (if any) did you change to?

(This question is copied from [Why did you stop using Tapestry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303438/why-did-you-stop-using-tapestry), which generated a lot of interesting, informed discussion from both sides.)

Answer (score 1):

JSF 2.0 has some improvements that handle most of the deficiencies in JSF 1.x, making it a very nice toolkit.

The real killer is that EL has been enhanced to take parameters to method calls.  That simplifies code immensely.